# How can I model table to be shared by other tables with 0 to many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first

I want to share `Contacts` entity between my `Customers` and `Vendors`.

`Customers` can have many `Contacts`

`Vendors` can have many `Contacts`

...but when I made my model I ran into a problem where now I have to supply both `CustomerId` and `VendorId` to each contact.

I'd post image of my model, but I don't have 10 points yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Customers` can have many Contacts
>
> `Vendors` can have many Contacts

As you said **Can** and not **Has** seems that the relation between `Customers` and `Contacts` and between `Contacts` and `Vendors` are zero or one to many.

So you could put `CustomerId` and `VendorId` `nullable`:

```
public class Contact
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public int? CustomerId {get; set;} 
   public int? VendorId {get; set;} 
   // other properties
}

public class Customer
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
   //other properties 
}

public class Vendor
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
   //other properties 
}
```

Comment: I'm using model-first. I do have set nullable to true on both properties. I changed to 0/1(Customer/Vendor)-many(Contact). When I tested database first, EF set nullable property to NONE. It works now and there are no errors, but I wonder if this is normal sharing `contacts` like this between tables or if there is more "standard" way of doing it.

Comment: In your project, can several customers or vendors have a given contact? Because with this structure, you cannot have the same contact linked to several customers or vendors.

Comment: No, I don't think it would make sense if contact is shared by both customer and vendor - should i reconsider this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with Many to Many relationships, you most likely have to use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

**That means having two additional tables with two columns each:**

- VendorsContacts with primary Keys :: VendorID, ContactID
- CustomersContacts with primary Keys :: CustomerID, ContactID

The primary keys of those tables **needs to be [compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key)**, i.e both keys together serve as a single primary key. In SQL Server that is achieved by marking both columns with CTRL and creating your primary key. You'll notice both of them being marked as primary.

EntityFramework won't be creating entity classes for the junction table, you will directly get access to the Contacts of a given Customer/Vendor through yourCustomer.Contacts and similarly yourVendor.Contacts.